# Is hardcoding controller, view and action names in MVC good practice?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

When looking over MVC code you will very often run into code snippets like below:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");

<li>@Html.ActionLink("Books", "Index", "Books")</li>
```

where controller names, controller action names or view names as provided as hard-coded strings. This is a common practice, but is it a good practice? After all if you rename controller, and forget to rename one of many references you would get a run-time error, rather than much more preferred compile-time error.

You could likely alleviate that issue by adding static Name property to your BaseController, and then use code as follows (action names would be slightly more difficult to accomplish).

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Books", "Index", BooksController.Name)</li>
```

So is this hard-coding something that should be considered as a lesser evil (over not using MVC). Or did people developed some practices to work around it?

Comment: Never ran into a situation where this came up, but I like the workaround and would use it if it did come up.

Comment: You're looking for T4MVC.

Comment: Indeed. Just watched the video. Would you like to make it an answer?

Comment: @Slaks: Please make it an answer. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [T4MVC](http://t4mvc.codeplex.com/), which generates strongly typed classes of string constants.

Answer (score 2):

Instinctively we know that string literals are a bad thing, so your gut instinct to make "Books" a constant would normally be good. The idea is to put the string in a single location, so when you need to change "Books" to "Products", say, you only have to change it in one place.

However, in doing so, you're messing up the very tools that will help you out. I just used Resharper to rename "HomeController" to "BananaController", and it automatically updated every reference of `@Html.ActionLink(... "Home" ..)` to `@Html.ActionLink(... "Banana" ..)`

I don't know if VS will do that without Resharper. VS is getting better at refactoring every year I'm told, but I don't actually work with anyone who doesn't have Resharper...

Comment: Yeah, R# is quite smart. I like that too, when I can navigate to code by clicking on those string literals. Still I feel like those literals should not be necessary.

Comment: If you want to do it like you'll read in the text books and sample apps, then I'd leave them as strings. That T4MVC that @SLaks mentions looks like a good next step. I'm contemplating how to move my MVC rendering off the server and onto the client, and getting rid of those strings altogether, but I guess I'll still need them to build the JSON. I'm going to check out T4MVC =)